# Is there a way to reduce this?

Tags: python

I have this code where st is an array of a class that have x and y parameters. I have to sort their x or y. How can i reduce it so i dont have to write the same code 2 times (one for each case)?

```
def sort(st, coor):
    for i in range(len(st)):
        if coor == 'x':
            selected = st[i]
            j = i - 1
            while j >= 0 and st[j].x > selected.x:
                st[j + 1], st[j] = st[j], st[j + 1]
                j -= 1
            st[j + 1] = selected
            i += 1
        else:
            selected = st[i]
            j = i - 1
            while j >= 0 and st[j].y > selected.y:
                st[j + 1], st[j] = st[j], st[j + 1]
                j -= 1
            st[j + 1] = selected
            i += 1
```

Comment: I think this might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Umm is this `st.sort(key=operator.attrgetter(coor))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract a method for the code that is duplicated.

https://refactoring.guru/extract-method

In that new method, the part that is different is calling the `x` or `y` attribute of an instance, and this can be replaced by a call to [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).